# How do I dynamically write to another html page on click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Right now I have a link to another page. I need to write information to a div in another html file based on what link someone clicks on in the current html file. For example, if I have options to choose between one one button or the other, I want to be able to write information to a div in another html file based on what button was clicked in the previous html file. Here's some example code:

index.html

```
       <h3>Starter</h3>

       <div>

           <a href="other_page.html" class="button small">Choose Plan</a>

       </div>
```

other_page.html

```
<div class="otherDiv">

    Write <h3>Starter</h3> here

</div>
```

Comment: is the information you write to the other page alot of text?

Comment: im just going to be passing 1 or 2 words at a time to a form on another page

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by adding a questionmark to the url and then search for it with javascript and add it to the desired div later.

only use this if there is not much information needed to be passed into the other page.
better solutions exists for longer strings.

```js
// this should be in the main js file, 
// or in script tags at the page where the div needs to be filled
$(document).load(function(){
let texttoadd = window.location.pathname.split('?');
$(".divtoadd").html(texttoadd);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- this is what the link in the main page should look like (you can add anything you need in the div on second page after the ?) -->
<a href="other_page.html?addthistothediv" class="button small">Choose Plan</a>


<!-- this is the div on the second page that will be filled with whater you fill in after the ? -->
<div class="divtoadd"></div>
```